# AWS Lambda python Error: Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'operatorPrecedence' from 'pyparsing'

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I just redeploy my AWS Lambda & accidentally face an issue:

```
[ERROR] 
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'operatorPrecedence' from 'pyparsing' 
(/opt/python/pyparsing/__init__.py)
(/var/task/pyparsing/__init__.py)
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you add more details about the code you are deploying--like folder structure and the dependencies you are including in the zip?

Answer (score 2):

I saw [a release note](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/2f633f4a3d1fa5b168f1d3390e3b5898cc27ab29/docs/whats_new_in_3_0_0.rst) that this feature was discontinued in version 3 of pyparsing:

> operatorPrecedence synonym for infixNotation - convert to calling
> infix_notation

So you may be including a different version of `pyparsing` than you have been using previously--one that does not include the `operatorPrecedence` functionality, so double check what version of `pyparsing` you are including.

[This Knowledge Center article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-import-module-error-python/) outlines the most common issues:

> You typically receive this error when your Lambda environment can't
> find the specified library in the Python code. This is because Lambda
> isn't prepackaged with all Python libraries.
>
> To resolve this error, create a deployment package or Lambda layer
> that includes the libraries that you want to use in your Python code
> for Lambda.

Here's a couple other examples that don't use layers if you want to include the dependency in the code package directly instead:

- https://alexharv074.github.io/2018/08/18/creating-a-zip-file-for-an-aws-lambda-python-function.html
- https://dev.to/razcodes/how-to-create-a-lambda-using-python-with-dependencies-4846

Comment: Thanks @shawn for clearly explain this issue 

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I fix this issue by following steps:

- make virtualenv
- manually add needed packages/library
- prepare requirements.txt by `python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- deploy your code

Note:

- After doing the above step, If you still facing the same issue,
- Then used  pyparsing==2.4.7 instead of pyparsing==3.0.6 OR updated version